# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js, express

I know this is obvious. I just can't see it.

This is part of a node/express app..

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./iresize.controller');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', controller.send);

module.exports = router;
```

Which leads to..

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at (/Code/server/iresize/index.js:4:18)
```

i.e. var controller = require('./iresize.controller');

I don't get it. I have lots of other routes and controllers that look exactly the same. I'm not sure why this one isn't working..

Note: I have cut down the error output for clarity. There is routes.js calling it like so...

```
  app.use('/r', require('./iresize'));
```

and then in iresize dir I have index.js and resize.controller files..

The full error output is as so:

```
node server/app.js 
[Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.]
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function._load (/Code/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Code/server/iresize/index.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function._load (/Code/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

NB: One of the Exceptions is at [this](https://github.com/keymetrics/pmx/blob/master/lib/transaction.js) file. However if I remove the app.use.. line above everything works fine.

Comment: how about showing this file: /Code/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21

Comment: That is this https://github.com/keymetrics/pmx/blob/master/lib/transaction.js

Comment: ah oops, didn't notice it was in the node_modules, so guess the code line is /Code/server/iresize/index.js:4:18 which might have the issue (well... whatever it is doing is causing the issue later in the code, you just took few steps back adn removed the app.use)